# Validation for file extension is not checking properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have written a validation for excepting files which has extension of `.xls` and `.xlsx` So here is the code below.

```js
function isFileValid() {
            var allowedFiles = [".xlsx", ".xls"];
            //  var allowedFiles = [".xls"];
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("MainContent_fluploadData");
            var fileChanged = fileUpload.value !== window.lastUploadedFilename;
            window.lastUploadedFilename = fileUpload.value;
            var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");

            if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()) && fileUpload.value !== '') {
                alert("Please upload files having extensions: " + allowedFiles.join(', ') + " only.");
                $('#MainContent_fluploadData').val('');
                return false;
            }
 }
```

So even if I am uploading valid excel file whose name is like :- `SITE_ADDITION (1).xlsx`

Please suggest.

Comment: How is it not checking properly? Where is it failing?

Comment: @mykaf: why it is not considering as `(1)` while uploading. ?? in the same file name with different version

Comment: I'm not great with RegEx, but sounds like you need to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Validation for file extension is not checking properly in jquery</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="file" name="file_input" id="file_input">
      <script>
           $("#file_input").change(function () {
              var fileExtension = ['xlsx', 'xls'];
              if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1){
                 alert("Invalid file type");
                 $(this).val('');
                 return false;
              }
              
          });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for regEx please use the below regex for your code.

```js
var regEx = new RegExp("^.*\.xls[xm]?$");//reg ex for excel file

console.log(regEx.test("abc.xlsx"));// true
console.log(regEx.test("abc.xls"));//true
console.log(regEx.test("abc.xlsm"));//true
console.log(regEx.test("abc.xlst"));//false
console.log(regEx.test("abc.doc"));//false
console.log(regEx.test("SITE_ADDITION (1).xlsx"));//true
```

Comment: it still giving me validation error.!!!

Comment: @Nad I  have added your file name. its working could you please explain error

Comment: `console.log(regEx.test("SITE_ADDITION (1).xlsx"));//false` why its false as the extension is `.xlsx` only. just filename is changing with different versions

Comment: @Nad have you run the program ?

Comment: yes, and it still giving me the error

Comment: @Nad its not giving erro over here. can create fiddle what you are trying

Comment: here is the fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/cofjp0d2/

Comment: please check and let me know.

Comment: new RegExp("^.*\.xls[xm]?$"); this is complete regex only for excel file. no need to add anything.

Comment: @NegiRox: `new RegExp("^.*\.xls[xm]?$");` has an un-escaped dot, which will incorrectly match `foo.yxls`. Better to write `new RegExp("^.*\\.xls[xm]?$");`, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about the extension use this:

```
function isFileValid() {
    var allowedFiles = [".xlsx", ".xls"];
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("MainContent_fluploadData");
    window.lastUploadedFilename = fileUpload.value;
    var regex = new RegExp('\\.(' + allowedFiles.join('|') + ')$', 'i');
    if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value)) {
        alert("Please upload files having extensions: " + allowedFiles.join(', ') + " only.");
        $('#MainContent_fluploadData').val('');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- you don't need to check for characters leading up to the `.` if you don't care about the chars in the file name, as long as you do not anchor the regex at the beginning.
- `'\\.('` - if you define a string and want to have a literal backslash you need to escape it: `\\`

  - in other words, string definition `'\\.('` becomes `\.(` in memory
- the second parameter to the `RegExp` constructor indicates case-insensitivity

If on the other hand you want to restrict the characters in the filename, use this:

```
function isFileValid() {
    var allowedFiles = [".xlsx", ".xls"];
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("MainContent_fluploadData");
    window.lastUploadedFilename = fileUpload.value;
    var regex = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9\\s_\\.\\-:\\(\\)]+\\.(' + allowedFiles.join('|') + ')$', 'i');
    if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value)) {
        alert("Please upload file with only A-Z, 0-9, space, dot, dash, :, () in name, and extension: " + allowedFiles.join(', '));
        $('#MainContent_fluploadData').val('');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- the regex needs to be anchored at the beginning with `^`
- tweak the character class as needed for allowed chars
- on the other hand, in case you have to full path name in your filename, start the regex string with: `'[\\/\\\\][a-z0-9...`